# ADO pipeline self-hosted: run some steps as admin and others as non-admin

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I need some steps of my Azure DevOps Pipeline to run as admin on the machine (e.g. to configure the build tools), and others to run as non-admin (e.g. to run unit tests that make sure perms are handled correctly by my code). All I know how to do is run the agent on the host as non-admin or admin. :-/

Comment: You could install two agents, one under an account with admin privileges, one without.